# How Resharper test runner run much faster than the Visual Studio one

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

I have a test suite that contains 700 tests. When I run them using Resharper, the total time is about 5 minutes. When I run them using Visual Studio 2017 it takes more than 45 minutes. What are the possible differences between these two tools that could affect the performance that much?

Extra infos: 
I'm using a lib to make my tests use a DB in-memory instead of a SQL one. To do so, I create a a transient connection before each test. It might seems a lot, but still, Resharper handle all tests in 5 minutes.
I use [Effort](http://entityframework-effort.net/?z=codeplex) for my in-memory connection.

Also, the tests running on Visual Studio seem to get slower and slower the more tests it executes. Is it possible VS doesn't dispose the connection the same way Resharper does?

I obtained the same results with Nunit and MStest

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using an old VS 2017 build, you have to follow this post, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/30/real-time-test-discovery/ The latest Preview build should already enable the new features. Microsoft is aware of the problems and working on it. How and why in such area is impossible to be answered at SO. Keep in mind that they are commercial products, not open sourced.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. That being said, it is not the discovery that is long, but the tests that are long to run.

Comment: Hi, do you have any info so far how to deal with it? I have similar problem